# C#: Выполнить действие исходя из отмеченных чекбоксов

Tags: c#, winforms, комбинаторика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть семь чекбоксов на форме, которые задают следующие параметры:

1. Публиковать без текста
2. Публиковать со своим текстом
3. Публиковать с подписью
4. Не копировать без фото
5. Не копировать без аудио
6. Не копировать без видео
7. Не копировать без текста

Так же есть функция, для которой можно задать некоторые параметры публикации (но не все, для остальных есть другой код). Вот она:

```
patterns.vknet.Wall.Post(new WallPostParams
{
    OwnerId = -yourcom,
    Message = yorTextBox.Text,
    Attachments = SetAttachments(),
    FromGroup = true,
    PublishDate = DateForPost()
});
```

И получается так, что для того, чтобы публиковать пост с нужными параметрами, нужно создать кучу if-else конструкций и обработать таким образом все варианты. И сколько комбинаций нужно для этого? Это сотни строк повторяющегося кода. Других идей у меня нет, в голову ничего не приходит. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Покажите что у вас внутри этих if

Comment: @PashaPash я пытался сделать вот так: https://i.imgur.com/J59i7Q0.png

Comment: приведите это кодом в вопросе, а не скриншотом :)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Determining which octant has a specific point](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95550/6143)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понял, как `публиковать` отличается от `копировать`, но эта штука явно раскладывается в последовательные if'ы, а не во вложенные:

```
if (chkПубликоватьБезТекста.Checked)
  текст = null;
else if (chkПубликоватьСоСвоимТекстом.Checked)
  текст = txtText.Text;
else
  текст = GenerateText();

подпись = chkПубликоватьСПодписью.Checked ? txtПодпись.Text : null;

if (chkНеКопироватьБезФото.Checked && !HasPhoto)
  return;

if (chkНеКопироватьБезАудио.Checked && !HasAudio)
  return;

if (chkНеКопироватьБезВидео.Checked && !HasVideo)
  return;

if (chkНеКопироватьБезТекста.Checked && string.IsNullOrEmpty(текст))
  return;

ВыполнитьДействие();
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться флагами.

```
[Flags]
public enum PostState
{
    NoText = 1 << 0,
    WithYoursText = 1 << 1,
    WithSub = 1 << 2,
    WithoutImage = 1 << 3,
    WithoutAudio = 1 << 4,
    WithoutVideo = 1 << 5,
    WithoutText = 1 << 6
}
```

Общее состояние формы можно хранить в переменной, например так:

```
var state = (PostState)0;
if (noTextCheckBox.Checked)
{
    state |= PostState.NoText;
}
if (yourTextCheckBox.Checked)
{
    state |= PostState.WithYoursText;
}
...
```

Далее логическая задача - сопоставить состояние формы и поведение. Что поменяется в том или ином случае, как можно это обобщить? Флаги помогут по крайней мере абстрагироваться от checkBox-ов и обдумать логику.